# Binding repositories to routes

Tags: binding, laravel, repository-pattern, laravel-routing

I'm using the Repository pattern in a way very close to the one Chris Fidao's used on [Implementing Laravel](https://leanpub.com/implementinglaravel) book. Basically I have concrete repository classes that implements its interfaces and gets models injected.

Now I want to take advantage of Laravel's route binding. Since I'm using repositories, I can't bind them to models directly... right? However I didn't get to do this.

I'm using a service provider to bind my concrete repositories to interfaces, like that:

```
    $app->bind('App\Repositories\UserInterface', function ($app) {
        return new EloquentUser(new User);
    });
```

How can I bind my routes to repositories interfaces? Seems to be trivial, but I'm a bit lost...

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Why would you want to bind a route to a repo? Routing should point to a request handler (more or less a service) not to a repository whose purpose is to decouple business from persistence

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different approach to pass a model to a form without binding a model to a route, for example, assume you have a route which uses `UserController` and this is the controller:

```
class UserController extends BaseController {
    public function __construct(UserInterface $UserRepo)
    {
        $this->repo = $UserRepo;
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = $this->user->find($id);
        return View::make('user.edit')->with('user', $user);
    }
}
```

Your form in the `user.edit` view:

```
{{ Form::model($user, array('route' => array('user.update', $user->id))) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Repo in your routes the following way. But, do you really need this?

```
\\the repo is in the Branches folder
use App\Repos\Branches\BranchRepository;

Route::get('branches',function(BranchRepository $branchRepo){
    \\using a method of your repo - in this case using getData() method
    return $branchRepo->getData();
});
```